# CodeIgniter displays error regarding setting the encryption key

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I already loaded the session and encryption libraries in *autoload*

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'encrypt');
```

And in my config file, I already set the encryption key,

`$config['encryption_key'] = 'seatplan_asi';`

But I still get the error
**In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.**

Comment: Is the `$config['encryption_key'] = 'seatplan_asi';` in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: yes. I changed the config file @Pattle

Comment: Have you tried testing with a plain key in the $config['encryption_key']? It's possible your path to seatplan_asi is off.

Comment: Did you try: $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']     = TRUE;?

Comment: Check you are on the right environment config in case you have multiple config

Answer (score 0):

set your $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 0):

I apologize. My mistake was there is already an
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
on the bottom of the file.